# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
var url="http://fsa.citop.in/lnct/service/signProcess.aspx";
var data={txtLogId: "abc@xyz.com",txtLogPass: "xyz",hdnReqType2: "sign87162"};
var success=function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
         };

var fail=function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log("Error:" + errorThrown );
     }
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data:data,
  success:success,
  error:fail,

});
```

This POST request gives me the error, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4`, in the console of the page 'http://fsa.citop.in/lnct/'  in chrome.

But if I use `fsa.citop.in/lnct/service/signProcess.aspx` (i.e. no http://), it gives me no error, but nothing comes back in data. On `success` of POST request, a JSON object is expected. Please somebody explain what is happening here and how it could be resolved.

Comment: Are you using `JSON.parse(data)` in your success callback? You will get the same error, because the function expects a string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's most likely because the response is HTML and it's trying to parse it as something else. The `<` at position 4 is the first < of `<!DOCTYPE html...`.

You should try to specify dataType in your ajax call (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and also make `signProcess.aspx` to return something more useful (currently the response content type is `application/json` but it prints HTML).

Comment: default dataType is Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)

Comment: setting dataType to text worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17):

For those who encounter this problem in AWS Lambda code editor it is most likely your session has timed out.

Try reloading the page and signing in again. 
It should resolve this.