# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3 in ionic 2

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ionic2

I'm having an error in Ionic 2 "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3". My json format is correctly structured using spring boot.

Below is my spring boot code.

Appreciate your help.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myview", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    List<Client> myView( @ModelAttribute("client") Client client){


        List<Client> data=(List<Client>) clientService.getAll();


        return data;
    }

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  people: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

load(){

    if (this.people) {

  return Promise.resolve(this.people);

  }

 return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/myview')
    .map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
       this.people=data;
       resolve(this.people);
     }, err=>{console.log(err)});
  });
}// end load function

}
```

JSON from /myview

[{"id":1,"username":"donald@yahoo.com","policy":"V121293031","name":"Donald","mobile":"0504735260","email":"dcgatan@gmail.com","address":"Dafza Dubai","amount":800.98,"datetimestamp":1472861297000},{"id":3,"username":"dcgatan78@gmail.com","policyno":"V38998933","fname":"Donald","mobile":"0501234567","email":"dcgatan@gmail.com","address":"MetDubai","amount":334.34,"datetimestamp":1472862939000},{"id":4,"username":"dcgatan@yahoo.com","policyno":"V34342323","fname":"Snoopy","mobile":"0501234567","email":"dcgatan@yahoo.com","address":"Metlife Dafza Dubai","amount":883.43,"datetimestamp":1472916463000}]

My http://localhost:8080/myview is not working because when I tried the below code with Array value it works. How to call the http instead of putting static values in the Array?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {

  people: Array<any> = [{"id":1,"username":"donald@yahoo.com","policyno":"V121293031","fname":"Donald","mobile":"0504735250","email":"dcgatan@gmail.com","address":"Dafza Dubai","amount":800.98,"datetimestamp":1472861297000},{"id":3,"username":"dcgatan78@gmail.com","policyno":"V38998933","fname":"Donald","mobile":"0501234567","email":"dcgatan@gmail.com","address":"MetLife Dubai","amount":334.34,"datetimestamp":1472862939000}];


  constructor(private http: Http) {}

load(){

    if (this.people) {

  return Promise.resolve(this.people);

  }

 return new Promise(resolve => {

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/myview')
    .map((res)=>res.json())
    .subscribe((data)=>{
       this.setPeople(data);
       resolve(this.people);
     });
  });
}// end load function

setPeople(data) {
      if (data) {
        for (let id of Object.keys(data)) {
          let item = data[id];

          item.id = id;

          this.people.push(item);
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to /myview would be returning incorrect json. It must be having HTML elements. Performing res.json() extracts data from _body of the response, if it's valid. But in your case it is throwing an error.

Comment: above is my json generated from /myview

Comment: Do one thing. Open your browser's developers console, open your source code there and apply a debugger at this line: (res)=>res.json()). When you run your code, the execution would pause there. At this point, hover over 'res' and let me know what do you see? If you can't find your code in developer's console, write debugger; after (res)=>res.json())

Comment: please check if I did it correctly (res)=>res.json(): (res)
arguments
:
[Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)]
caller
:
[Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)]

Comment: Why are you accessing the call stack? Did you pause and hover over res?

Comment: Also, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814694/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-4

Comment: I'm getting this on my log, EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Comment: Clearly there are 2 things: your call is unseccessful / response in incorrect json. If you paste http://localhost:8080/myview in your browser address bar and hit enter, what exactly do you get in the response?

Comment: I solved it already. The reason why it is not accessible is because of the security I created to access the url.